# bind child control of a tabitem to another object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabitem, collectionview

In my MVVM Application I have an object in my `MainViewModel` called `Products`;
I Also created a `CollectionView` to enable navigating in those `Products`. What i need is to show the `CollectionView.CurrentPosition`.

`MainViewModel.cs`

```
    private CollectionView collectionView;

    public CollectionView CollectionView
    {
        get { return this.collectionView; }
        set
        {
            this.collectionView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => CollectionView);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Products = fillProducts();
        CollectionView = (CollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Products.Items);
    }
```

Now for displaying the items in the `Products`:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabProductsView"
                     DataContext="{Binding Products.Items}"
                     Header="View Products">
    <textBlock Text="{Binding ProductID}" />
    <textBlock Text="{Binding ProductDesc}" />
    <textBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
...
<TextBlock name="CurrentItemPosition" Text ="{Binding CollectionView.CurrentPosition}"/>

</tabItem>
```

Now, binding to the `Products.Items` is working probably and i can navigate through my products and view the details . But viewing the `CollectionView.CurrentPosition` is not working (not showing anything) cause I already set the `DataContext` for the hole `TabItem` to Products.Items. Also setting the `DataContext` of the `CurrentItemPosition TextBlock` is not working.

Any ideas on how I can display the `CollectionView.CurrentPosition` under this `TabItem`?

In other words, how would I bind to another `Object` from the `MainViewModel` in the same `TabItem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i tried to bind directly to the CollectionView itself and now everything is working fine ...